# Distribute iOS app without paying for developer account

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution, iphone-developer-program

I was wondering if there was a way to distribute an app for free without enrolling in a paid developer account from Apple.  I was using services like Pgyer and HockeyApp, but it only works when I download it to my device, and not someone else's device.  What could I do that won't make me drop $99 on a developer account?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The only way you can do this is to release your source code and let your users build the app on their machine and side load it on their device. Either that, or distribute it for jail broken devices.

Answer (score 8):

No there is no way to distribute ready-made apps to other users of non-jailbroken iOS devices without a paid Apple developer account.

If your target is jailbroken devices the answer is different.

Similarly, as @BeauNouvelle points out, if your target is other developers, you can post your source code to a site like Github and others can build the app.

You could also partner with a licensed developer who could post the app for you. If the app is a public-service type app you could likely find a developer willing to do so. You would have to give them the source and other project files and they would build the app. If you go this route, set up the licensing such that the other dev is not allowed to charge for it, and ownership remains with you. You'd also want an NDA in place to protect your intellectual property rights.

Comment: Re-read the first sentence of my answer. No third party can re-sign your app for others to use. They would have to build the app from source using **their paid** developer acct.